# recyclerview can not be sync or founded

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I need to add recyclerview to my project but the elements of the recyclerview not appear.

**This my dependencies:**

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

[image: Shows the Error]

Comment: do you want to see items in preview? use `tools:listitem="@layout/your_row_view"`

Comment: i want to see like item1, item2 and etc in my recyclerView

Comment: I can't see error image please load again !

Comment: Would you please share your xml code?

Comment: @KaranMer 's comment is the only reliable answer here; besides those Firebase libraries are outdated.